# jQuery cloned objects not being picked up

Tags: jquery, clone

I have two tables and each row within both tables have a `<td>` with a checkbox. Currently, when something is checked on the second table, it copies that row (using `.clone()`). When a row in the first table is unchecked, it should be removed from the first table.

This works perfectly fine for rows that were in the first table upon page generation. But the cloned rows do not fire off the jQuery and I was wondering what approach I should take to fix this.

Here is the jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3BZp4/21/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `true` as the [first argument of `.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to ensure that events already registered on those elements get copied too.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Kr248/

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I thought it might be something to do with the events. Glad it was simple

Answer (score 1):

pass true to clone() API like `.clone(true)` so that event handlers are copied

Answer (score 0):

that happens because selectors like `$('#featured tbody tr td input.checkbox').on(...)` can work only for `tr` already in page, so try to change in this way

```
$('#featured').on('change', 'input.checkbox', function(e) {
...
})
```

and

```
$('#offers').on('change', 'input.checkbox', function (e) {
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to fix your problem

Comment: there's no need to resort to event delegation, and in jQuery 1.7 delegation _is_ done with `.on`